# Make the window always maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**How can I make my application run only with the window maximized?**

I am working on a project where I need the window to always be maximized or else the interior designs begin to clump together (please do not comment on the formatting of this app).  I understand how to easy it is to set the WindowState to "Maximized" but I need to get rid of the users ability to re-size the application (except the fully minimized option).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984300(v=vs.71).

Comment: @mech I agree that this information is readily available (look at all of Robert Harvey's links), but that question in particular was referring to WinForms. This is for WPF.

Comment: I was trying to do this with minWidth and minHeight.  The question mech posted did not even contain an answer and the only similar solution was done in the property window which I try to steer clear of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following attributes.

```
ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowState="Maximized"
```

Hope that helps.

[More information on the ResizeMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`ResizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx):

```
<Window ...
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
        WindowState="Maximized">
```